# Variable not getting assigned to an array in windows cmd (.bat file)

Tags: arrays, batch-file, cmd

I want to read a .txt file that has listed the names of some other files, like this:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

I'm trying reading the file line by line, and the content from each line in an array:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set _file=c:\path\to\some\file.txt

set n=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%_file%) do (
   set _files[!n!] = %%a 
   echo %%a
   set /A n+=1

)
for /l %%n in (0,1,!n!) do ( 
   echo !_files[%%n]! 
)
```

The first echo will succesfully show me that "%%a" has the name of the files, however it isn't getting assigned in the array, so every time I call the values the result I get is `ECHO if off`

¿Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Well currently you're setting a variable named `_files[!n!]<space>` to the value `<space>%%a<space>` so to view that variables value you'd need to use `!_files[%%n]<space>!`. Better to set it correctly in the first place, using the recommended syntax, `Set "Variable=StringValue"`, i.e. `set "_files[!n!]=%%a"`.

Comment: Additionally, as your final value of the variable named `n` was set within another code block, you don't need to delay it's expansion outside of that block. Instead of `for /l %%n in (0,1,!n!) do (` you could have used `for /l %%n in (0,1,%n%) do (`.

Comment: That made the trick! I'm just starting to learn to program in this files, so this kind of things goes over my head. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It's not appropriate to edit a question to provide the solution in that question. If you've solved the problem and want to share the solution, do so by writing an answer in the space below designed for that purpose - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my comment as an answer.

Currently you're setting a variable named `_files[!n!]<space>`
 to the value `<space>%%a<space>` so to view that variable's value you'd need to use `!_files[%%n]<space>!`.

It would be better to set it correctly in the first place, using the recommended syntax, `Set "VariableName=StringValue"`. *Spaces however are acceptable/ignored when setting integers via `Set /A`*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "_file=C:\path\to\some\file.txt"
Set "n=-1"
For /F "UseBackQEOL=?Delims=*" %%a In ("%_file%")Do (Set /A n+=1
    Set "_files[!n!]=%%a"
    Echo %%a)
For /L %%n In (0,1,%n%)Do If Defined _files[%%n] Echo !_files[%%n]!
```